# How to hide index wxWidgets wxGrid

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets, wxgrid

How can I hide or remove default index on wxGrid?
I've been searching in wxWidgets's Documentation, and couldn't find it.

This is the picture of wxGrid:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To hide the row labels you can use [wxGrid::SetRowLabelSize(0)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid.html#a9072318969deffab8fcf99694e5a4943).

Answer (score 2):

`HideRowLabels()` will also hide the row labels!